# How to make iframe website view in fit without scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe

how to make my iframe view website fit from header to footer?
Below i use Wikipedia for an example. When i viewed it, it not show Wikipedia footer. I want iframe viewed it all.

```
<iframe src="https://www.wikipedia.org/" style="height: 100%; width:100%; border: none" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Comment: http://bit.ly/1S5SZHF

Answer (score 0):

you have to wrap it in a container with:

```
height: 100vh
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xLypur5L/)

Answer (score 0):

remove margin in body by adding the following Css property to html body     margin: 0px;
this will work fine on chrome browser meens you mean to remove all browser defaluts with something like that as browser add some properties which make that diffrence

http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/